# Modifying a specific value under a child node in Firebase for android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and currently I'm making my project using Firebase as backend. But I'm having this issue. I have my Firebase database structure like this:-

```
    root:
child1:
      value1:
      value2:
child2:
      value1:
      value2:
```

and so on. I want to edit/modify value2 under child 1. How can i do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference c1v2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("child1").child("value2");
c1v2.setValue("Value");
```

Please start here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: thanks for the answer man. i have one question , will thw value2 will be child of child 1 ? i have inserted those values into child 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

I was facing some issues when using the above code ,finally after modification i got my solutions .This will modify your matching child's inside value

**NOTE**

users

+child1-value1

+child2-value1

```
DatabaseReference dbrefrence= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("username", "COMPLETED");
    dbrefrence.child("users").child("child1").updateChildren(result);
```